# Redirect administrator login page of multiple Joomla websites hosted in Apache server

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, .htaccess-configuration, redirect, regex

I have around 10 Joomla websites hosted on Apache server. The admin URLs are similar to below patterns.

```
http://m1.aa.example.com/administrator
http://m2.aa.example.com/administrator
           .
           .
http://m5.aa.example.com/administrator
http://m1.bb.example.com/administrator
http://m2.bb.example.com/administrator
```

Common pattern can be identified as,

```
http://[one letter & digits].[two letters].example.com/administrator
```

The part `example.com/administrator` remain unchanged.

I need to redirect users to relevant home page of each Joomla website if users try to go to URL with above pattern.

What I did so far :-

Add below directive in **httpd.conf** file

```
<IfModule alias_module>
  Redirect permanent /(\.)[a-z]*\/administrator /(\.)[a-z]*  
</IfModule>
```

However this is not working. Can someone give a solution for this?

Comment: Whenever you require a well-crafted regular expression, you should provide at least 3 very realistic sample strings.  The more realistic the samples and the more samples that you provide, the more accurate the pattern can be.  A dot doesn't need to be wrapped in parentheses.

Comment: What do you want to do with the user that has to access /administrator to maintain the site? Or why are you trying to redirect people to the homepage, is it a security issue? There are some plugins that do the redirect for you that I could suggest if I understood more about your requirement.

Comment: @mickmackusa please check the edit.

Comment: @Irata I'm going to evaluate set of users on their Joomla knowledge and had given a deadline to create Joomla websites. So after the deadline users should not be able to access admin to do any changes. considering this scenario can you give me a solution? Also the number of Joomla websites can increase. So I will need a solution which can be applied to all the Joomla sites in the server.

Comment: Redirecting isn't really my bag, but if you only mean to trim the `administrator` off, shouldn't this work?  `Redirect permanent /(\.[a-z]*)\/administrator $1`  A good place to test patterns: https://regex101.com/r/DRGLAV/1/  Or maybe you mean to grab the whole domain before `.com` which could be loosely done with `.+` https://regex101.com/r/DRGLAV/2/ .

Comment: I was thinking of some plugins that hide the directory or temporary support access to a site but nothing that would have a single point of update like you are after. Otherwise if your 'students' have a set amount of time to achieve something a plugin that will hide the admin page x days or hours after they first login could be written.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for your answer, I think this pattern should work. need to check whether this will work in Apache configuration file.

Comment: @Irata your solution of hiding admin page x days is what I'm looking for but as u have identified, it has to be easily done with a single point update.

Comment: A plugin on each instance could query a common URL or file location that you maintain to get its date/time to expire and this could be done the first time they login to set the param in the plugin or each time they login to see if they should be redirected. You could also have different expiry date/times/periods based on the domain name.